# How can i call the post in an asp core reactjs app?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I currently have the following in my reactjs javascript file

```
  details.js

       const response = await fetch('users');
```

this then calls the mvc controller which is below

UsersController.cs

```
   private readonly ILogger<userController> _logger;

    public userController(ILogger<userController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<user> Get()
    {
        <code goes here>
    }
```

The problem is that the fecth calls the Get , hwo can i call any routine in the controller ?
So if i had a few more routines like the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<user> UserDetails(string Id)
    {
        <code goes here>
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<user> UserInfo(string name, string Id )
    {
        <code goes here>
    }
    [HttpId]
    public IEnumerable<user> UserId(string firstname, string lastname, string companyId)
    {
        <code goes here>
    }
```

How can i call these from the details.js file ?

is it like the following

```
    const response = await fetch('users/UserInfo');  ?
```

Comment: I don't understand asp core but i think you are calling http post endpoint with get request. Change the fetch to `fetch('url', { method: "POST" })`.

Comment: How would that work , as each routine has a different signature ? How do i call those ? There are Post and Get routines ?

Comment: Use different http method?

Comment: Yes so if i want to call  UserId(string firstname, string lastname, string companyId) ?

Comment: would i need to put a route on the routine ?

Comment: I can't help you with the asp core part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell .NET framework about the parameters of the endpoints and use correct HTTP methods for calling them. For example, the Id argument of the UserDetails method can be used as a URL segment by changing your code slightly:

```
[HttpPost("{Id}"]
public IEnumerable<user> UserDetails(string Id)
{
   <code goes here>
}
```

The HttpPost attribute tells .NET framework that it's a **POST** endpoint. Notice the {Id} part of the HttpPost attribute. It's a placeholder that you should replace with the actual ID when calling the endpoint. To call that endpoint, you have to send an HTTP POST request to the **"users/123"** endpoint where the "123" part is the replacement of the {Id} placeholder. Here is an example:

```
fetch('users/123', { method: "POST" })
```

The endpoint URLs can also contain query string parameters. For example, here is how you can use query string parameters for calling the UserInfo endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("{Id}"]
public IEnumerable<user> UserInfo(string Id, [FromQuery] string name)
{
    <code goes here>
}
```

Notice we added the FromQuery attribute to the "name" argument of the UserInfo method. The FromQuery attribute tells .NET framework that the URL should contain a query string parameter called name. Your endpoint URL will become **"users/123?name=john"** where "123" is the replacement for the {Id} placeholder and name=john is the assignment of the "name" query string parameter to value "john."